# Alternative to notepad++ analyse plugin for Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, software-recommendation, log, text-editor, notepad-plus-plus

I am not allowed to install wine in my ubuntu 18.04, so I cannot install notepad++.

Is there any alternative to Notepad++ Analyse Plugin, as some text editor which supports similar functionality.

List all instances of particular text, multiple text in order of their occurrences.

```
Example
Abc
def
123
Abc
123

Filter logs:
Abc
123
Abc
123
```

I installed Atom, but it can find and list only one search.

Please suggest.

Comment: For people coming for similar question. Two alternative I found glogg and clog, not that powerful but can be used

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++ (*notepad-plus-plus*) is a snap package in the default repositories of all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. To install Notepad++ open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install notepad-plus-plus
```

To add Notepad++ navigation to other drives besides the default drive:

```
sudo snap connect notepad-plus-plus:removable-media
```

[image]
<sup>Even though the window title says [Administrator] this file is opened with normal user permissions in Notepad++.</sup>

To install AnalysePlugin in Notepad++ select *Plugins* → *Plugins Admin…* -> *Available* tab → check *AnalysePlugin* -> click  <kbd>Install</kbd>  button in the top right corner as shown in the below screenshot.

[image]

After restarting Notepad++ the options for AnalysePlugin will be shown in *Plugins* → *AnalysePlugin*.

Comment: The reason I am looking for alternatives is I am not allowed to install Notepad++. snap socket has been blocked by administration

Answer (score 0):

I am answering slightly differently, because it seems to be an XY problem. Most likely you are trying to get a list of unique lines, and if it's a log, you are not very likely to want to edit it. Therefore, you are unlikely asking for an editor, this is just what you have used on Windows, so think that no other way is possible.

On GNU/Linux a better alternative would be to use `uniq` command in the terminal. Simply pipe any output into it, and it will remove duplicate lines. For example if you have a file `~/logs/log1` you can simply do:

```
cat ~/logs/log1 | uniq
```

and you will get all the unique lines. If the list is too large and you want to be able to scroll you can do:

```
cat ~/logs/log1 | uniq | less
```

and finally if you do want to edit the file afterwards, you can simply output to a different file and then edit it

```
cat ~/logs/log1 | uniq > ~/logs/log1-filtered
```